# Wordpress: Change menu based on JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, menu

My current problem is ti change the menu being loaded in my `header-top-area.php` file based on the value of a javascript variable I've created.

So far, I've written a simple script that identifies the width of the user's monitor, and based on the width, the value of `displaySize` is either `desktop` or `mobile`.

```js
function displaySizeReader() {
    if (screen.width < 992) {
        let displaySize = 'mobile';
    }
    else {
        let displaySize = 'desktop';
    }
}

displaySizeReader();
```

In my header file, I have code that displays a custom menu, but I'd like to change the code so that it's an `if` statement that loads a different menu based on the JS variable value. I've taken the basic `if` statement structure and I think this how it would be structured, but I know that my equality statement is incorrect as the php code doesn't recognize the JS variable. I think my next step would be to assign the JS variable to a php variable like `$displaySize`, but how exactly would I go about that conversion?

```php
                <div class="row">
                    <?php if (displaySize == 'desktop'): ?>
                        <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array( 
                            'theme_location' => 'desktop-custom-menu', 
                            'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) ); 
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (displaySize !== 'desktop'): ?>
                        <?php
                        wp_nav_menu( array( 
                            'theme_location' => 'mobile-custom-menu', 
                            'container_class' => 'custom-menu-class' ) ); 
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
```

Comment: Let me reframe your thought process. Output the HTML for both menus, and change the show/hide based on JS. Or, even better, use native CSS media queries to show hide the menus, no JS needed.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for the quick reply. I initially suggested CSS media queries as I know that's the standard route, but my manager specified that he would like it done via php and JS if possible for other plans he has in the future. The issue with outputting both menus and hiding one is that a screen-reader would still pick up on the hidden menu, and this would cause us issues with accessibility, which this site has a large focus on.

Comment: I’m a manager. I like when people push back. I don’t always agree, but I respect it. There are ways to mark DOM items as `disabled` for accessible users. JS and PHP can’t talk directly to each other. First, JS needs a host, which is HTML, which also needs a host, which is HTTP, followed by PHP and WordPress. So HTML and thus PHP comes before JS. You _could_ make an AJAX call after load for the menu, but this is 2022, and the problem has been solved for a very long time already.

Comment: @ChrisHaas I like your answer and I think I'm going to take your advice on it over my managers. It sounds too convoluted to go through all those steps so instead I think I'll go the HTML + JS route and look for an option to hide the inactive menu from users. 

Would you happen to have any good articles/examples I could reference to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have 20+ years of experience, no articles. However, visit most major sites online and compare the “desktop” DOM with the “mobile” DOM, including the accessibility tree, and you will have plenty on examples